# Connection error Firefox (V39) and Selenium Webdriver (2.47.1)

Tags: java, maven, firefox, selenium

i can not build a connection between my Firefox Version 39 and my Selenium 2.47.1

Here the pom part:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.47.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here my simple Startcode for the firefox driver:

```
new FirefoxDriver();
```

And here my Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
(x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"39.0","st":1436516697011,"mt":1435711164000}},"winreg-app-global":{"{D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\McAfee\\SystemCore","e":true,"v":"IDS_SS_VERSION","st":1437984529042,"mt":1396606131173}}}
1438851828765   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of fxdriver@googlecode.com
1438851828771   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of XXX@xxx.de
1438851828771   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {6e84150a-d526-41f1-a480-a67d3fed910d}
1438851828771   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1438851828772   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60}
1438851828774   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"XXX@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\XXX02\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous3876026029653398132webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":true,"v":"2.44.0","st":1438851826787,"mt":1438851826694}},"app-global":{"XXX@it.nrw.de":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\XXX@XXX.xpi","e":true,"v":"15.06.24","st":1435640800968},"{6e84150a-d526-41f1-a480-a67d3fed910d}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{6e84150a-d526-41f1-a480-a67d3fed910d}.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.5.6.1-signed","st":1433154279318},"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"39.0","st":1436516697011,"mt":1435711164000}},"winreg-app-global":{"{D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\McAfee\\SystemCore","e":true,"v":"IDS_SS_VERSION","st":1437984529042,"mt":1396606131173}}}
1438851828775   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1438851828778   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1438851828778   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1438851828778   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1438851828778   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1438851828779   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1438851828779   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1438851828782   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1438851828782   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1438851828782   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1438851828782   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1438851828782   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1438851828782   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
JavaScript warning: resource://cck2/Preferences.jsm, line 556: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
JavaScript error: chrome://vscore/content/scriptff.js, line 3: Error: couldn't open library scriptff.dll: error 126
console.error: 
  [CustomizableUI]
  Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node
JavaScript error: file:///C:/Users/XXX02/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3876026029653398132webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js, line 11487: TypeError: this.server_ is undefined
JavaScript error: chrome://fxdriver/content/server.js, line 38: NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80570015 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.createInstance]
1438851829477   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1438851829477   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1438851829477   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Selenium support firefox version till 33 only. Please check in detail here `https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES`

Comment: if you dont want to downgrade search for `firefoxPortable` version 33.

Comment: Thanks, but your link has no changes after 2.45... Here are more https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG

Answer (score 0):

Firebox version 39 is not supported by Selenium Webdriver (2.47.1). Please check the compatibility of the version and I suggest you should use Selenium version-2.40.0 that supports Firefox 27, 26.

Try above suggested versions. It will surely resolve user issue.